# Can Light Waves Be Irregular?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, photons

From what I understand, electromagnetic radiation produced by an antenna is of the frequency that corresponds to the motion of the electrons moving around in the antenna. And I assume that the electrons in most set ups are generally vibrating in an approximately sinusoidal motion. But sinusoidal is definitely not the only periodic shape we can get electrons to vibrate in. We can have square waves or saw-tooth waves.

My question is is there any detectable difference or any additional theoretical property individual photons have that are produced or carry some other non-sinusoidal wave shape, or are photons' energy states fully described by their frequency?

To be clear I'm interested in the resulting properties of individual quanta and not statistical group properties.

Comment: A multi-frequency broadcast (i.e. anything but a pure sine wave) will be made up of multiple photons.

Comment: Sunlight is pretty "irregular", if you want. It contains a wide range of frequencies and if you want to express that with quanta, you can do so using an ensemble. An individual quantum, OTOH, is just a single measurement on the field, so it can't tell you very much about the ensemble. That's no different from the classical case, where a single wave sample can't tell you much about the entire wave, either.

Comment: Remember that a square or saw-tooth wave is simply a combination of several sinusoidal waves at certain frequencies and amplitudes. When you get down to it, a (co)sine wave is really the only fundamental periodic shape you can have.

Comment: @Jim I understand that mathematically we can decompose (almost) any  complex wave into  an infinite Fourier series. But that fact alone doesn't necessarily imply that every physical electromagnetic wave isn't just approximated by but exactly equal to a finite combination of perfect (co)sine waves.

Comment: @JonCuster If that is true, would you mind expanding that into an actual answer with perhaps examples or sources?

Comment: It doesn't exactly imply that, but it mostly does. $E=h\nu$. The energy of a photon is determined by its frequency. Anything but a sine wave isn't just one frequency, it's a combination of frequencies. Because energy is quantized, each one of those frequencies *must* have at least one quantum of energy, ie at least one photon per frequency.

Comment: +1 for a good question, however.

Comment: @Jim: Energy isn't quantized. It can (and is) being exchanged in arbitrary quantities. The reason why energy exchange in quantum-electrodynamics happens in quanta is because angular momentum is quantized.

Comment: @CuriousOne Energy is exchanged at arbitrary quantities because frequency is not quantized. But at any specific frequency for EM waves, there is a minimum, non-zero amount of energy and in that way, energy of EM waves becomes quantized.

Comment: @Jim: That's not true, either. There is no known lower limit for energy exchange and the universe is certainly full of very soft photons from infrared radiation of cold bodies. I don't know why this is perceived as important, anyway. Maybe it is unfortunate that we are "initiating" quantum mechanics with the photo-effect, which is easily misunderstood as energy quantization?

Comment: @CuriousOne You are saying the same thing I just said except you prefaced it with "That's not true". I believe my comment indicated that energy has no lower limit because frequency is not quantized. Any amount of energy can be transmitted. The important distinction I made was the at any ONE specific frequency, the energy of a photon is given as $E=h\nu$. One cannot have an EM wave of that same frequency with lower energy because you need at least one photon to constitute a wave. The photon can lose energy, but then it changes frequency.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Although you might drive your antenna (and the internal electrons) with a sawtooth wave, the resulting antenna emission is decomposed into "modes" of the antenna, which depend on the length, shape etc.  The Mode will correspond to photons (well, in antennas you usually think of Electromagnetic waves) which can radiate, and electromagnetic waves only self-propel themselves if the Electric & Magnetic fields are Sines or Cosines (since the relations between electric & magnetic fields are time derivatives; a sine creates a cosine and vice-versa).

So I think the "photons" will still be described as sinusoids.  However, the antenna will probably output many different frequencies of photons (EM-waves), so the sawtooth wave will look like it's been decomposed into however many sinusoidal EM-waves by the antenna.
Any photon that couldn't be described as a self-propagating sinusoidal wave would instead be "evanescent" - it will die out quickly, eg. a decaying exponential.

Whether the "photon" is really a sawtooth shape, or is really a superposition of many sinusoids, is sort of due to how we define photons and electromagnetic waves - presumably you could describe the same situation *without* only sinusoidal electromagnetic "photons" (or photon-packets as it were), but that's how all the math I've ever seen does it.

Comment: The modes of an antenna are not photons and photons are not described by periodic functions. It doesn't even make sense to talk about photons, unless you are talking in a quantum field picture, which most certainly is not useful for macroscopic antennas. You have certainly never seen math that describes photons as sinusoids, at least not in a textbook worth keeping.

Comment: You are free to make your answer factually correct and I will remove my down vote.

Comment: Antennas are always described using waves, but the OP is asking about photons - conceptually these two are related, since with lasers, for example, you use both descriptions simultaneously. So I'm thinking the "photon" here would be some quanta of energy in the wave, the minimum that could be absorbed by another antenna.

Comment: I'm more interested in helping this guy understand rather than the number of arrow clicks I get. If you have something useful to add feel free to improve the answer yourself.

Comment: That the OP doesn't, yet, understand that photons are quantum field measurements and not classical or semi-classical objects is no excuse for a false answer. Nothing stops you from talking about photons correctly. If you look at _correct_ quantum descriptions of lasers, then you will find the language of quantum field theory all over the place (i.e. creation and annihilation operators). Using those doesn't really make much sense for antennas, unless you are also throwing a density matrix in, which really won't return much beyond classical Maxwell.

Comment: Go ahead and write a correct one, I'd love to see it.